# Textbox data is reflected in ddl twice

Tags: c#, asp.net

I fill one textbox and transfer that data in DDL field.DDL already have data by database value and transfer data showing in the 0 positions of the DDL but zero position repeated in the DDL.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string set = Request.QueryString["state"];


     Bond();

     ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(set));
 }

 void Bond() {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 10  * from Login",con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ddl.DataSource=ds;

        ddl.DataBind();

        ddl.DataTextField = "USERNAME";
        ddl.DataValueField = "ID";
        ddl.DataBind();
 }
```

Comment: You mean two items with same text show up in DDL?

Comment: Are there 12 items in your dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

Try executing the code in page load event conditionally as given below.

So, on intitial page load i.e. when `Page.IsPostBack == false` the logic of inserting item at 0 index happens. In your case, every time the page posts back the same item gets added again and therefore you see the 0 item added twice.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!Page.IsPostBack) {
         string set = Request.QueryString["state"];

         Bond();

         ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(set));
      }
}
```

Also, as suggested in another answer, call DataBind method only once in your Bond method (i.e. remove the first DataBind but keep the last DataBind in Bond method). There is no need to call it twice.